# Is there anyway to access Picasa albums (hidden) by ID without login in?

Tags: c#, web-services, oauth-2.0, google-api

I used to have my Picasa albums shown on my website. I didn't do anything to it the last couple of years, and the Google API has changed since.

Is there still a way to access an album (that is accessable through a link without login) if I have the album ID? I can't get it to work.

I have no trouble with the oAuth login. But I use that for the back-end. I can't let front-end visitors login with google (as me) to access my albums (ofcourse).

So I was wondering, if I save the album ID in the backend, is there still any way to access the album using the api if the album is set to "visible to people with a link"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, it states in the documentation **When your application requests non-public user data, it must include an authorization token.**

Is there a reason why you aren't making the album public seeing as it will be visible on your website anyway?

I guess you could do something like set up another account and use that to get the authorisation token, all a bit messy though.

Comment: Well, I used to use picasa just as a picture-host on my personal site. I had my site behind a login page, so only family could enter. And by getting the images from picasa, I didn't need a lot of webspace or traffic. 

Back then, I could login by just sending my credentials to the API. Now with oAuth, that seems impossible. You always get the popup asking if you are willing to permit the access.

But thanks for the answer. I must have missed that part.

Comment: @Cryothic In that case then, you should be securely storing the refresh token and using that to get a new access token when it expires. Have a look at the detail here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer